# questions out of turn

Tags: meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*out of turn*" in this [article](http://nypost.com/2015/08/27/donald-trump-booted-univision-anchor-for-raving-like-a-madman/):

> Donald Trump booted Univision anchor Jorge Ramos from an Iowa press conference because Ramos ***yelled questions out of turn*** and was raving like a madman, the candidate said Wednesday.

According to this [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/turn), two definitions seem to work:

> definition 9 under section Phrases:  At a time when it is not one’s turn.
>   definition 10 under section Phrases: Speak in a tactless or foolish way

Which definition would fit the usage in the article?

Answer (score 1):

Your first definition applies in this instance.

It was not Ramos' turn to ask questions since he had not been called on as can be seen [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87StHeTQR4&ebc=ANyPxKr0kgIdOyQmqH-PgOBZI5e1FMX0upvkwFdoP7reH_YA554SjHpWVcDB8NVVof-nTEA1JdW-dxYTBe-krzlet-cCZyuCJA).
Ramos later returned and had a lively exchange with Trump.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily the first is accurate, though also the second, to a degree.

The first, literal, definition applies as he was indeed not speaking when it is his turn.

However you have to consider the fact that the phrase is normally meant in a negative fashion. The implication is that he is lacking the ability to participate in the press conference reasonable, i.e lacking in tact. Note that it isn't always the case that both definitions apply.